# Is there a way to associate a Keyboard with a Label?

Tags: roku

guys I'm stuck on the way to announce invalid data entry on keyboard elements when Audio Guide is enabled. I have in mind to show the errors using the text attribute on a Label component, but what freaks me out is that I haven't found a way to associate the keyboard with that label. In HTML, aria-discribedby on form fields will save the day but in Roku, no clue. I have search all over the internet and no results. Summarizing the question: Is there a way to associate a Keyboard with a Label? Any Roku Accessibility tips are a great help. Thanks beforehand!